# Google actions builder - how to read from webhook request and avoid empty response

Tags: php, webhooks, actions-on-google, google-assistant, actionbuilder

When I call webhook using PHP, I get this message while testing. Sorry, I didn't get any response
Attached my webhook request json and
and php code

```
if($method == 'POST')
{
 $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $json = json_decode($requestBody, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
 $customer_name=$json["requestJson"]["intent"]["params"]["customer_name"]["resolved"];
 $response = array ('prompt' => array ('firstSimple' => array ( 'speech' => $customer_name, 'text' => 
 $customer_name)));
 echo json_encode( $response );
}
```

also webhook response json while testing

```
{
"responseJson": {
"prompt": {
  "firstSimple": {}
}
 }
}
```

[image]

Webhook request json

[image]

Comment: What does `var_dump($requestBody);` show? Please update your post accordingly so we can see the raw data coming in

Comment: @hppycoder could you please provide an example how i would send back that JSON object. That would be very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it shows up in the test console, the "requestJson" attribute isn't part of the body that is sent to you. The body will just include the object underneath that attribute.

So the line to get `$customerName` should probably be more like

```php
 $customer_name=$json["intent"]["params"]["customer_name"]["resolved"];
```

The specific reason you're getting the error about not getting a response is because there aren't any attributes set in the "simpleResponse" attribute of the response. I'm assuming that is because `$customer_name` ends up not getting set, so either php or the Assistant are removing null attribute values.

Comment: Thanks prisoner its working now. thanks for your great help